# Avoid using activesheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code below.  I get a 400 error when I try to run it.

```
Sub sbInsertingColumns()

Dim NumRows As Long
Dim Transit As Worksheet

Set Milestone = ActiveWorkbook
Milestone.Activate

Set TransitFile = Workbooks.Open("Y:\File.xlsx")
TransitFile.Sheets("General").Activate
Columns("A:B").Copy
End Sub
```

The code will work if I change

```
  Columns("A:B").Copy
```

to

```
ActiveSheet.Columns("A:B").Copy
```

Why is that?  I thought I already made the General sheet in the TransitFile active by activating it?

Comment: Instead of activating your sheet you should just use "With"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TransitFile.Sheets("General").Columns("A:B").Copy` without having to activate the sheet beforehand. Or you could have used a `With` to refer to the correct Workbook.